# How can I export data from query in excel to a dat file?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am using PowerQuery to perform some operations on a large data set (35 million rows) and then add it to a data model.

The data for current year comes in a certain format whereas old historical data is in another format. I had to perform a bunch of operations on historical data to bring it to the same format as the current year data.

Now the combined (historical + current year) data is added to the data model. I am looking for a way to export this data to a .dat file from the PowerQuery model. Is there a way I can do this ?